# Regex error in paste

Tags: r, regex

I use this paste option which have some regex expression:

```
a <- paste("/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, \' \');")
```

the initial regex expression is:

```
(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ')
```

and I receive this error:

```
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(/[\n\r]+|[\s"
```

any idea what can I use to make it to see the whole regex expression acceptable?

Comment: Try `\\s`, `\\\s`, and `\\\\s`

Answer (score 1):

Use four backslashes with your escape characters.  Two will yield a literal backslash, and the other two handle the escape character.

```
a <- paste("/[\\\\n\\\\r]+|[\\\\s]{2,}/g, \' \');")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I guess I should expect when I press a I should give back the initial `(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ')` but I take this `"/[\\\\n\\\\r]+|[\\\\s]{2,}/g, ' ');"`

Comment: So did my answer help your problem?  I think you have an escaping problem.  Not sure if you need two or four backslashes though.

Comment: Sorry but it is not the expected. I tried the \\ or \\\ for s but it is not working. I can't understand why \n and \r works without additional \ and s has this problem

Comment: Please update your question and show us what actual string you need, and how that string will be used.  Keep in mind that if you plan on feeding the string into a regex engine, this may require extra handling.